# How to integrate Stripe Connect with Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, stripe-payments, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I need help to create a module that uses Stripe Connect with Drupal 8.7, Drupal Commerce 2.14 and Commerce Stripe RC3 :

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe

Currently there is no module with Drupal 8 to use Stripe Connect, it's a shame because Drupal Commerce makes it easy to set up a marketplace (a site with several merchants).

I set up my Stripe account to use Stripe Connect on the page :

https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications/settings

I want to use Standard Stripe accounts and charge a 10% commission on each transaction :

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges

Here is a diagram of what I want to do :

https://stripe.com/img/docs/connect/direct_charges.png

I found some documentation to integrate Stripe Connect :

https://stripe.com/docs/building-extensions

There is a patch for Commerce Stripe but it does not work :

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe/issues/3032908

How can I charge 10% commission on each sale ?

I created a role in Drupal "premium merchant" :

- When a merchant connects his Stripe account, the "premium merchant" role must be added.
- When a merchant disconnects his Stripe account, the "premium merchant" role must be removed.

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) to ask if they have specific guidance, but generally you'd use [stripe-php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

Comment: @taintedzodiac stripe-php is with the Commerce Stripe module of Drupal 8. I just want to create a module based on Commerce Stripe.